# PostgreSQL ERROR: trigger error when inserting new data

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I created the following trigger, however when I try to insert some data in the table, the following error occurs: "control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN".

I'm using the SQL Manager Lite for PostgreSQL version 5.9.5, I've tried changing the RETURN Null to RETURN NEW but when I try to compille, the same error occurs.

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.saida3 IS NOT NULL THEN
     UPDATE ponto
     SET banco_de_horas = "interval"((saida1 - entrada1) + (saida2 - entrada2) + (saida3 - entrada3) - '08:00:00')
     WHERE "time"(entrada1) < '22:00:00' AND "time"(entrada1) > '06:00:00' AND saida3 IS NOT NULL;
     RETURN NULL;
      ELSE IF NEW.saida2 IS NOT NULL THEN
       UPDATE ponto
       SET banco_de_horas = "interval"((saida1 - entrada1) + (saida2 - entrada2) - '08:00:00')
       WHERE "time"(entrada1) < '22:00:00' AND "time"(entrada1) > '06:00:00' AND saida2 IS NOT NULL;
       RETURN NULL;
     END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

The trigger is to calculate the comp time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any PostgreSQL function should be finished by `RETURN` statement.

Your code is not well formatted and it is not well readable

```
BEGIN
  IF NEW.saida3 IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE ponto
       SET banco_de_horas = "interval"((saida1 - entrada1) 
                            + (saida2 - entrada2) 
                            + (saida3 - entrada3) - '08:00:00')
      WHERE "time"(entrada1) < '22:00:00' 
        AND "time"(entrada1) > '06:00:00' 
        AND saida3 IS NOT NULL;
    RETURN NULL;
  ELSE 
    IF NEW.saida2 IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE ponto
         SET banco_de_horas = "interval"((saida1 - entrada1) 
                            + (saida2 - entrada2) - '08:00:00')
       WHERE "time"(entrada1) < '22:00:00' 
         AND "time"(entrada1) > '06:00:00' 
         AND saida2 IS NOT NULL;
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
  END IF; --<<< THIS branch is not closed by RETURN
END;
```

After reformatting, you can see a path where the `RETURN` is missing.

I don't understand to your case, so I cannot to fix it, but for this code, I think so `RETURN null` can be only one as last statement of the trigger function.

Comment: Thanks for claryfing that the functions should hava a RETURN statement, and adding the RETURN to the end of it worked, thanks, I will use the `RETURN NEW` since the function will calculate and set this value to the field.